# How can you modify headers in a chrome extension in Manifest Version 3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to modify headers on a tab using a chrome extension. It is possible in MV2, however that is going to be deprecated in 2023 and I want to update my extension to MV3.

Comment: Use declarativeNetRequest, more info in the official [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: I've seen it - but I don't know exactly how to modify web requests with it. @wOxxOm

Comment: There are tons of examples in the documentation and in the internet. If those won't help, show your MV2 code and describe what is the exact problem with implementing it in MV3.

Comment: I do not think there is a way - especially to view the request headers using declarativeNetRequest api in manifest v3. @SamiAliÖzdemir were you able to?

Comment: Nope. you can't read headers in Chrome extensions anymore. Only append, remove, or set. @Venu

Comment: So firefox is going to have this in their road map of manifest V3. Not sure though since it is still under the hoods. Link here : https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2022/05/18/manifest-v3-in-firefox-recap-next-steps/

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you redirect to one example that answers the question?

Answer (score 3):

Docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/

Sample manifest-

```
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest", 
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess", 
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/", "https://*/"],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Sample rules.json file-

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "requestHeaders": [
        { "header": "h1", "operation": "remove" },
        { "header": "h2", "operation": "set", "value": "modified-v2" },
        { "header": "h3", "operation": "set", "value": "h3-value" }
      ]
    },
    "condition" : {
      "urlFilter" : "|http*",
      "resourceTypes" : ["script", "main_frame", "sub_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to update dynamically-

```
function updateDynamicRules(headerKey, headerValue) {
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    addRules: [
      {
        id: 1,
        priority: 1,
        action: {
          type: 'modifyHeaders',
          requestHeaders: [
            { 
              header: headerKey, 
              operation: 'set', 
              value: headerValue
            },
          ],
        },
        condition: {
          regexFilter: '|http*',
          resourceTypes: [
            'main_frame',
            'sub_frame',
            'script'
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
    removeRuleIds: [1]
  }, async (result) => {
    console.log('created', result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here are examples from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "priority": 2,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        { "header": "h1", "operation": "remove" },
        { "header": "h2", "operation": "set", "value": "v2" },
        { "header": "h3", "operation": "append", "value": "v3" }
      ]
    },
    "condition": { "urlFilter": "headers.com/123", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        { "header": "h1", "operation": "set", "value": "v4" },
        { "header": "h2", "operation": "append", "value": "v5" },
        { "header": "h3", "operation": "append", "value": "v6" }
      ]
    },
    "condition": { "urlFilter": "headers.com/12345", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).